# Backbone 1.1.2 with lodash 3

Tags: backbone.js, lodash

Lodash 4 [claim to work](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Migrating#backbone) with Backbone >= 1.3.0

we are still working with Backbone 1.1.2 - what are our options? currently we use a custom build of lodash 1.2.1.

Is lodash v3 is compatible with that version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*jdalton* (the main contributor to lodash) claims that it should just work (i.e. lodash 3 *is compatible* with backbone 1.1.2). so, in regards to *the backbone code*, everything should be fine.

see [this comment on a github issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-cli/issues/32#issuecomment-71536180) that poses the same question as yours.

regardless, you should check out lodash's official docs on [compatibility warnings for version 3](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#compatibility-warnings-1), and update *your code* wherever necessary.